# How do I mock a constructor with Mockito so I have access to the real object?

Tags: java, mocking, mockito, powermockito

For a singleton class I can use something like:

```
public void test() {
Foo foo = new Foo();

try (MockedStatic<Foo> staticFoo = mockStatic(Foo.class)) {
staticFoo.when(() -> Foo.getFoo()).thenReturn(foo);
foo.setVariousValues();
fooManipulator.makeNewFooAndDoStuff();
...
```

However I need to do use this for objects that aren't singleton, that are instantiated by:

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
```

Using Mockito.mockedConstruction I see I can

```
 try (MockedConstruction mocked = mockConstruction(Foo.class)) {
 Foo foo = new Foo();
 when(foo.method()).thenReturn("bar");
```

Which basically makes the constructor return a Mockito.mock(Foo.class), but I don't want a mocked Foo, I want a real Foo object that I have access to.

In PowerMockito this was possible as so:

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
PowerMockito.whenNew(Foo.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(foo);
foo.setVariousValues();
fooManipulator.makeNewFooAndDoStuff();
```

Is this possible or out of the scope of the new inline static mocks?

Comment: Change your class' design to accept a factory in its constructor, then inject a factory instance in your test which keeps track of the created objects. No need for Mockito.

Comment: @knittl Thank you, that works for my use case. Still wish I could do the mocked one since its just a tool that was taken away by the upgrade...